# .Net Core Worker Service load production credentials/env

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm newbie in .Net. I just started last 2 weeks.

I'm currently building a worker service that will be installed in a windows platform ( window service ) on different machine of our clients.

I have this struggle now on how or where to store the production credentials. In my development setup, I used the user secrets but in documentation user secrets can only used for development.

Would like to know ideas on how do you usually set your production env/credentials?